# Convert several json files into a single dask dataframe and save this dataframe in a database

Tags: python, json, dataframe, dask-dataframe

I have a large number of json files in a folder. I would like to read them and save them in a single database. I had thought of pandas dataframes to do this but due to the large number of files, this operation is very slow. Someone suggested dask, which also has dataframes and seems to be very fast, so I installed it and did some tests. It seems to be confirmed. but unlike pandas, the dataframe just contains the content of each json as text. Can someone tell me how to do this so that I get a single dataframe with all the json files read and with the column names of the keys of each object in each json as well as the values?

### pandas code

```py
import pandas as pd


data = []
folder = '20-05-2019'
json_files = get_json_files(folder)
for json_file in json_files:
    df_temp = pd.read_json(json_file, encoding='utf-8')
    data.append(df_temp)

df = pd.concat(data)

df.head(10)
```

### result

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CHUm.png]

### dask dataframe code

[image: code+result]

### sample folder with 7000 json files in each folder (3000 folder in total)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/au9s1.png]

### sample json

```json
[
    {
        "sector":"AAA",
        "code":"0009",
        "id":"00000001",
        "fname":"FirstName",
        "lname":"LastName",
        "height":"158",
        "dob":"01/03/2006",
        "din":"19/05/2019 13:23",
        "dout":"19/05/2019 17:46",
        "type":"some text",
        "group":"2",
        "dod":"19/05/2019 13:48",
        "desc":"some text",
        "details":"some text",
        "feval":"Triage 1",
        "localisation":"some place",
        "infop":"not yet implemented",
        "is_in":true,
        "is_op":false,
        "list_c":[],
        "list_e":[],
        "list_a":[],
        "list_r":[]
    },
    {
        "sector":"AAA",
        "code":"0009",
        "id":"00000001",
        "fname":"FirstName",
        "lname":"LastName",
        "height":"158",
        "dob":"01/03/2006",
        "din":"19/05/2019 13:23",
        "dout":"19/05/2019 17:46",
        "type":"some text",
        "group":"2",
        "dod":"19/05/2019 13:48",
        "desc":"some text",
        "details":"some text",
        "feval":"Triage 1",
        "localisation":"some place",
        "infop":"not yet implemented",
        "is_in":true,
        "is_op":false,
        "list_c":[],
        "list_e":[],
        "list_a":[],
        "list_r":[]
    },
    {
        "sector":"AAA",
        "code":"0009",
        "id":"00000001",
        "fname":"FirstName",
        "lname":"LastName",
        "height":"158",
        "dob":"01/03/2006",
        "din":"19/05/2019 13:23",
        "dout":"19/05/2019 17:46",
        "type":"some text",
        "group":"2",
        "dod":"19/05/2019 13:48",
        "desc":"some text",
        "details":"some text",
        "feval":"Triage 1",
        "localisation":"some place",
        "infop":"not yet implemented",
        "is_in":true,
        "is_op":false,
        "list_c":[],
        "list_e":[],
        "list_a":[],
        "list_r":[]
    },
    {
        "sector":"AAA",
        "code":"0009",
        "id":"00000001",
        "fname":"FirstName",
        "lname":"LastName",
        "height":"158",
        "dob":"01/03/2006",
        "din":"19/05/2019 13:23",
        "dout":"19/05/2019 17:46",
        "type":"some text",
        "group":"2",
        "dod":"19/05/2019 13:48",
        "desc":"some text",
        "details":"some text",
        "feval":"Triage 1",
        "localisation":"some place",
        "infop":"not yet implemented",
        "is_in":true,
        "is_op":false,
        "list_c":[],
        "list_e":[],
        "list_a":[],
        "list_r":[]
    },
    {
        "sector":"AAA",
        "code":"0009",
        "id":"00000001",
        "fname":"FirstName",
        "lname":"LastName",
        "height":"158",
        "dob":"01/03/2006",
        "din":"19/05/2019 13:23",
        "dout":"19/05/2019 17:46",
        "type":"some text",
        "group":"2",
        "dod":"19/05/2019 13:48",
        "desc":"some text",
        "details":"some text",
        "feval":"Triage 1",
        "localisation":"some place",
        "infop":"not yet implemented",
        "is_in":true,
        "is_op":false,
        "list_c":[],
        "list_e":[],
        "list_a":[],
        "list_r":[]
    },
    {
        "sector":"AAA",
        "code":"0009",
        "id":"00000001",
        "fname":"FirstName",
        "lname":"LastName",
        "height":"158",
        "dob":"01/03/2006",
        "din":"19/05/2019 13:23",
        "dout":"19/05/2019 17:46",
        "type":"some text",
        "group":"2",
        "dod":"19/05/2019 13:48",
        "desc":"some text",
        "details":"some text",
        "feval":"Triage 1",
        "localisation":"some place",
        "infop":"not yet implemented",
        "is_in":true,
        "is_op":false,
        "list_c":[],
        "list_e":[],
        "list_a":[],
        "list_r":[]
    },
]
```

#### EDIT for further information

> Maybe I didn't explain well enough why I put everything in a dataframe first. In fact, in each json a certain amount of information is stored about people and this data is updated at regular intervals. At the end of the day, the backup operation in the database takes place. So it is sometimes and often a question of duplicate data between files that must be processed before saving everything in the database.
>
> This means that the files cannot be processed individually. You have to group them all together in a single dataframe (this is the best idea I have at the moment).

Comment: Please do not link your code or images, but include them here in a minimal and reproducible way. You should not expect people to follow unverified links.

Comment: Is the *output* of your code the `head()`? What you do with the data will affect how you should load it. If you want a single massive dataframe in memory, dask might now be able to help.

Comment: please provide sample json.  It looks like you should be able to read multiple json to dataframe: https://examples.dask.org/dataframes/01-data-access.html

Comment: @mdurant Once the data is loaded into the dataframe, and some calculation and cleaning operations are done, I have to save it in a database.

The `head()` is mainly to get the structure of the dataframe I want to get.

with pandas i can do `dataframe.to_sql(...)` with `sqlalchemy` and i want to be able to do the same thing with the obtained dask dataframe.

Comment: I cannot see the code you tried, or any idea of why it failed. I have given you the likely solution below anyway.

Comment: @mdurant 
I tried this code

```python
import os.path as path
import json
import dask.bag as db

folder = '20-05-2019'

ROOT = path.join(DATA_ROOT_FOLDER, folder)
mybag = db.read_text(f'{ROOT}/*.json').map(json.loads)

ddf = mybag.to_dataframe()
ddf.compute()
```

Comment: *This* comment is not the place! Please put it in the question

Answer (score 0):

As often happens, the answer is actually simple - you do not need *any* of dask's dataframe API for this, you will be acting on your files one-by-one. This requires no interaction between the tasks, and no output, so you can just use the `delayed` function.

```
from dask import compute, delayed

@dask.delayed
def process(file_name):
    df = pd.read_json(json_file, encoding='utf-8')
    df.to_sql(...)

tasks = [process(fn) for fn in json_files]
dask.compute(*tasks)
```

This probably makes heavy use of the python interpreter, so you will find the above cannot use all the cores when in a single process. I would recommend you use `dask.distributed` to create a local cluster with as many processes as you have cores, and one thread per process.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain well enough why I put everything in a dataframe first. In fact, in each json a certain amount of information is stored about people and this data is updated at regular intervals. At the end of the day, the backup operation in the database takes place. So it is sometimes and often a question of duplicate data between files that must be processed before saving everything in the database.

This means that the files cannot be processed individually. You have to group them all together in a single dataframe (this is the best idea I have at the moment).